# Little image next to name

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table (like in football) where the names are selected from my database with:

```
SELECT * FROM db ORDER BY points DESC;
```

Now, I would like to add a little image of a medal next to the winner from last season, but how to do so? Every name have an ID, so I thought something like:

```
if ($row['id'] == 1)
echo '<img src="medal.jpg">;
```

where 1 is the ID of the winner from last season, but I don't know how to make it appear.

The list of people are written like this:

```
<td><strong>'.$no.'</strong></td>
<td>'.$row['name'].'</td>

<td>'.$row['games'].'</td>

<td>'.$row['points'].'</td>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: `if (is_winner($row['id'])){echo '<img src="medal.jpg">;}`  - just write finction `is_winner()` to check it.

Comment: @IvanBolnikh Can you help me with that function? I'm pretty new at this, sorry ..

Comment: where you want to add this image?

Comment: @AlivetoDie right next to the name :)

Comment: How and where you store 'who is winner' information?

Comment: show your table structure  please

Comment: @IvanBolnikh Well actually I don't store it. I just thouhgt of writing a variable like ˋ$winner = 1ˋ where 1 is the ID from my database table :)

Comment: then check the answers below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if winner flag is in same table then directly u can check the status and display the medal as below.

```
if ($row['winner_flag']==1)){ //condition as per the flag.
echo '<td>'.$row['name'].'<img src="medal.jpg"></td>' ;
```

if winners list is in another table then write a function to check the winner and add below condition.

```
if (is_winner($row['id'])){ echo '<td>'.$row['name'].'<img src="medal.jpg"></td>';} 

finction is_winner($id)
{
//Sql query to get check the winner status based on id and return the value as boolean.
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I actually didn't store the winner in db but I just made a variable and used your code. :)

Comment: @DanielJensen: Glad to know that my answer is useful, upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($row['id'] == 1) { $uimg ="medal.jpg"; }
if ($row['id'] == 2) { $uimg ="Silvermedal.jpg"; }
etc...

<td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
<td>'.$row['games'].'</td>
<td>'.$row['points'].'</td>
<td><img src="your path of image folder/'.$uimg.'" width="16" height="16"></td>
```